# Asynchronous commit on Postgres over iSCSI with BBU storage

Tags: postgresql

It is my understanding that it's alright to turn `synchronous_commit` off if your server has a local, battery backed up storage controller.

In my environment I am on a VM whose block storage is connected via iSCSI, where the iSCSI node is using DRBD and both the primary and secondary nodes have battery backed up controllers.

FWIW, here's the specifics:

- PostgreSQL 9.3
- CentOS 6.3 (VM)
- VMware 5.1
- Infiniband QDR transport
- SLES 11 iSCSI nodes
- DRBD
- LSI BBU SCSI controllers with CacheCade Pro 2.0 (in-use).

Can I safely turn off `synchronous_commit`?

Comment: It isn't clear what improvement you expect to get from this change. Are you suffering from commit latency problems? If so, how fast are `fsync()`s on your system? Run `pg_test_fsync` and post the results in an edit to your question, then comment here when done so I see the new info.

Comment: Craig's answer addresses the configuration option you're proposing very well. It's worth mentioning that a batter backed disk controller should return from synchronous writes as soon as they are cached by the controller ("write back" configuration). Battery backed controllers should generally not be configured for "write through" as the cache then isn't used to speed up writes.

Answer (score 6):

> It is my understanding that it's alright to turn synchronous_commit off if your server has a local, battery backed up storage controller.

Actually, that's kind of backwards. Turning `synchronous_commit` off is unsafe no matter what, in that it permits the database to *lose recently committed transactions* if it crashes. This is true with, or without, BBU or crash-safe SSD storage.

What `synchronous_commit = off` does is allows you to trade durability for speed when you're on storage where flushes are expensive so you want to batch them up and want to avoid client latency while apps wait for flushes. It has much less effect on storage where flushes are fast, since you do less waiting for commits to happen - so it's pretty much all downside and little benefit.

In general, you should *not* set `synchronous_commit` off globally. As the documentation advises, you should `SET LOCAL synchronous_commit = off` in specific transactions that you don't need to be durable, leaving it enabled otherwise. That way you might lose transactions you're not so fussed about, but not the ones that're making important changes.

If you can't afford potential loss of transactions that clients think are committed at all, you may instead want to consider a `commit_delay`, which pauses to try to batch a few commits together before flushing. This can produce a throughput improvement on I/O subsystems with really slow flushes without sacrificing durability.

You may also want to consider using `UNLOGGED` tables for specific tables you can afford to lose in a crash. If Pg crashes while the table is dirty it'll truncate it and you'll have to re-populate it, but there'll be no wider database corruption.

If anyone tells you to turn `fsync` off - please don't. It should be called `eat_my_data = on`, and is totally unsuitable for anything except throw-away instances where you can easily reconstruct the lot after a crash.